# How to make the "live views" in the Taskbar icon groups start displaying contents when they were started minimized?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Every day, numerous times, I start some long-running scripts like this:

```
start /min cmd.exe /C php "C:\a\path\to\a\file.php"
```

This makes them immediately minimize (as to not bother me) and group themselves into a "cmd.exe" Taskbar icon group. So far, so well.

When I then click the Taskbar icon group, it brings up previews of these windows, but instead of showing the "live view", they just show a generic cmd.exe icon for each:

[image: XXXXXXXXXX]

Only by clicking each of these manually does it start displaying the actual "live view" (and then keeps on updating it from that point on). This is very annoying, especially if it happens 54 times a day, every day.

How do I make these "live views" start updating without me having to manually focus them? I need them to start minimized.

Comment: If they are minimized, then they haven't drawn anything, so there is nothing to show.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. They *have* "drawn" (outputted text), yes... But it's not updated until you focus them. Please read.

Comment: Outputting text merely puts information into the screen buffer, but they haven't been painted into graphics memory.

Comment: What are you saying? Do you not understand the question? Is something unclear about what I asked?

Comment: You are confusing the application running inside the console with the console itself. At any rate, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: It's a question about Windows, as categorized. And PHP, if it can be done from within it.

Comment: The thumbnail shows what has been rendered. A minimized window does not render.

Comment: Except it does, but only after it has been "kickstarted" by focusing... Why are you flat-out making things up?

Comment: If you re-minimize it, the preview stops updating because the console has stopped rendering.

Comment: Please stick to the topic. I don't know what you are saying or how it relates to my question.

Comment: The preview shows what was most recently rendered. Minimized windows do not render. In programming terms, they need to receive `WM_PAINT` messages and call `BeginPaint` and then render into the DC. This doesn't happen for minimized windows, so all that can be shown is what the window rendered most recently. If the window has never rendered, then there is nothing to show. You need to make the window render. This is not something can be done from a PHP program.